# HTML table text displaying in a single vertical line

Tags: html, html-table

This is seriously a generic question, and I'm not able to paste the code in here for trouble-shooting so apologies for that in advance.

My question, to which I have googled endlessly this afternoon, but clearly I lack google-fu power here ... is that is there any particular reason why text would display in a vertical line in a HTML table?

I've tried like everything ... this is for a HTML email btw, tried `white-space: pre-wrap;`, `white-space: nowrap;`, etc ...

Obviously `white-space: nowrap;` is not an optimal solution ... and nothing else works!

I cannot for the life of me figure out why, why, why does the text display in a single line?!?!?!?

Comment: Why can't you paste a mock up of the HTML that is causing you problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Make sure that you have a width set on your table columns - either fixed or percentage based. Also wrap your text inside of the cells in `<p>` tags if possible. Otherwise the columns will collapse to the narrowest possible width, which in your case is the width of a single character.